# Glassfish - No route to host

Tags: http, networking, glassfish, connection, appserver

In our enterprize application, App-server (Glassfish) connects to a Content Management system to get some static content to be displayed on web pages.  Connection is made through:

```
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient
```

There are 4 App-Servers to server user's HTTPRequests and all of them connects to this content management system to fetch static content.

Let's assume CMS URL that App-Server connect to is : `http://somedomain.com/content`

This mechanism works fine without any issue, but sometimes one of these App-server starts throwing:

```
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

This exception appears from just one of these serverthat indicates there is no global issue with the connectivity to Content Management System. When this exception occurs I even tried hitting the CMS through web browser by typing `http://somedomain.com/content` in address bar and that works fine.

When we restart the affected Server, problem disappears.

Would like to know what can dynamically introduce this error?

Comment: Just a thought, are performing a shutdown on the http client?

Comment: It sounds like there is a resource limit on the server which is being reached. Possibly there are no more TCP/IP ports to connect with. Take a look at this (possibly pertinent) issue-:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572215/how-to-avoid-a-noroutetohostexception