# Getting exception "HTTP transport error: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Cannot assign requested address"

Tags: java, linux, web-services, cxf

Im getting the below error while trying to call a webservice with the client generated using cxf. I have tested with 1000 concurrent request,up to 100k I'm getting good results. But after that the exception mentioned below is occurring. Can anyone help me to solve this.Can this be overcome by setting any server/network parameters

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Cannot assign requested address
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:121)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:142)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:83)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:587)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:546)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:531)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:428)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:211)
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572215/how-to-avoid-a-noroutetohostexception

Comment: thanks lahu89 ;  But  we are calling  client generated by cxf and we dont have any facility to programize the port reusability and we also have tried parameters like echo "1" >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse ,but problem was not fixed.Does any other option available like controlling any server parameters or tomcat parameters to solve the same