# Apache DefaultHttpClient - java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I am running a performance test in a Java "client" accessing a Tomcat 8.5 web server. After about 13,000 requests HTTP request fails with the error,

```
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
```

The code is,

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 15000; i++) {
        try {
            if (i % 1000 == 0) System.out.println("Iterations: " + Integer.toString(i));
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:9080");
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request, new BasicHttpContext());
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Iterations: " + Integer.toString(i));
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

If I cache the DefaultHttpClient the error does not occur.
Also tried,

```
        request.releaseConnection();
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

But does not change the error.
The error does not seem to be cause by the client. If I access another website in the URL it is okay. Seems to be caused by Tomcat in Windows running out of file handles or socket resources or something.
If I run it again as another process right after it crashes, it will fail in 1 run not 13,000, so the issue is Tomcat running out of resources.  Seems like DefaultHttpClient is not closing its connection, or Tomcat is not freeing its connections until a gc occurs.

Using HTTPClient 4.2.5

Any ideas why it occurs, or how to fix?

Comment: The error is caused by the client. You are running out of local ports, so there must be a connection leak. Possibly not in this code.

Comment: It is clear that you are expected to cache the client. It will do connection pooling, but it can't if you keep instantiating new instances.

Comment: If the issue is the client running out of ports, then why does it not occur if I use another URL than the local tomcat? Seems like it is related to the server. This is the only code for the test, where is the connection leak?

Comment: Does DefaultHttpClient not release its connection after executing a request? Adding the releaseConnection() and getConnectionManager().shutdown() does not change the behavior.

Comment: Have you tried `client.close()` or wrapping the client in a try-with-resources? In my code I find the interfaces `CloseableHttpClient` and `CloseableHttpResponse` and both are closed via try-with-resources.

Comment: Using 4.2.5, no CloseableHttpClient or close()

Answer (score 5):

I couldn’t reproduce the same error you have. Anyways when I ran your example in single thread I receive NoRouteToHostException.

```
13:37:57.917 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager - Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl@2c7ceffa
Iterations: 16329
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Can't assign requested address (Address not available)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
        at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:605)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:440)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at com.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:25)
```

You are opening connections at the rate faster than it takes to close the connection - Closing a socket is held in TIME_WAIT status before they are released to be available for new connections.

For testing purposes only you can set the [tcp_tw_reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1600905/2683814) to allow TIME_WAIT sockets to be reused.

On my OSX I could change the max segment lifetime for testing and the error disappeared.

sudo sysctl -w net.inet.tcp.msl=1000
net.inet.tcp.msl: 15000 -> 1000

`DefaultHttpClient` is backed by `BasicClientConnectionManager` which create and manage single connection and keeps only one active connection at a time for any route.

When the connection is released back to connection manager it is kept alive for reuse and is marked as reusable.

> If I cache the DefaultHttpClient the error does not occur.

That is exactly the solution. I believe correct way to be use single http client and allow the connection managers to do its job.

All the connection management is explained in [apache documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.2.x/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html)

4.2.5 is pretty old (April 2013). If your starting on a new project it would make sense to update to latest(4.5.12) at the time of writing.

References:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPCOMPONENTS/FrequentlyAskedConnectionManagementQuestions

https://raby.sh/osx-where-are-my-time_wait.html

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are using HttpClient with a wrong way (i.e probably copy-paste old legacy snippet)

- First of all one client is enough (for one thread).
- According to the [httpcomponents-client documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html)
  it's better to use pooled connection management
- Your response should be closed

I.e.

```
  PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
  CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
          .setConnectionManager(cm)
          .build();
  HttpContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
  try {
    final HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:9080");
    for(int i = 0; i < 15000; i++) {
      CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request, context);
      try {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
      } finally {
        response.close();
      }
    }
  } finally {
    client.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using 4.2.5, your code is based on new classes in a newer version that do not exist in 4.2.5

Answer (score 1):

Best Practice is to use MultiThread `HttpClient`. Below should work :

```
package com.demo.httpclient;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class ThreadedHttpClientTest {

    private static URI rootUri = URI.create("http://localhost:8080/");
    private static int worker = 100;
    private static int count = 15000;

    private static HttpClient httpClient;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        PoolingClientConnectionManager poolingClientConnectionManager = new PoolingClientConnectionManager();
        poolingClientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(worker);
        poolingClientConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(worker);

        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(poolingClientConnectionManager);

        List<Callable<Void>> workers = new ArrayList<Callable<Void>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            workers.add(new WorkerThread(httpClient, rootUri.toString()));
        }

        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(worker);

        int i=0;
        for (Future<Void> future : pool.invokeAll(workers)) {
            future.get();
            System.out.println("Response " + i++);
        }

        System.out.println("Time Taken :: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + "ms");
        pool.shutdown();
    }

    static class WorkerThread implements Callable<Void> {

        HttpClient client;
        String url;

        public WorkerThread(HttpClient httpClient, String url) {
            this.client = httpClient;
            this.url = url;
        }

        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get, new DefaultClientConnection());
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```